# DbSet.Find() doesn't work for Guid properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-expressions

I have two models

```
public class QChoice : ModelWithGuid
{
    [Required]
    public Guid? QId { get; set; }
}

public class ModelWithGuid
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

I'm performing FInd opertion on CHOICE Dbset.

```
DataContext.QChoice.Find(choice => choice.QId.Value.Equals("Guid")).ToList();
```

From the above line Find Operation calls below method.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
  var resultData = table.Find(predicate);//table means QChoice DbSet
  yield return resultData;
}
```

I'm getting error like "The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet.Find' was of type 'Expression>', which does not match the property type of 'Guid'".Please help me

Comment: Wonder if you found the solution to this. It is working on my local machine but not on the server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-3.1) documenation,

EF Core `DbSet<TEntity>.Find` does not take any `predicate` rather it takes the primary key of the entity as object as follows:

```
var qChoice = DataContext.QChoice.Find(choice.QId);
```

Moreover if you want find with predicate than update your `Find` method as follows:

```
public T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
     var resultData = table.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
     return resultData;
}
```